# apache velocity and webpack manipulations

Tags: javascript, spring, webpack, velocity

I use a [apache velocity](https://velocity.apache.org/) engine for generate my web pages.
In last time I added [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) to my project for do some manipulations of my .js and .css files.
But, I can't find some plugin that can do that for my .vm files, for example, remove comments from my .vm files.
Maybe someone know a right pattern for do this?
Thank you.